# Headers and footers with Logo input

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

In the MWE below, the logo top left is making some trouble as of it is size I assume. Due to the small margins top and bottom "20mm" its pushing the page number too low. Is there a way this can be done avoiding that or due to the size of the image it is hard?

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=20mm,right=19mm,bottom=20mm,left=38mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array,float,graphicx,epic,eepic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{Omar Sammour}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{soton.png}}
%\rhead{Omar Sammour}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Headers and Footers}

\newpage
\textbf{Headers and Footers 2}

\newpage
\textbf{Headers and Footers 2}

\end{document}
```

[image: The line is too close to the test for some reason]

[image: Page number too low]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: The compilation depends on the `soton.png` file. Is there any way to provide this file? In addition, I assume that the `headheight` option of `geometry` must be changed

Comment: Regarding the headheight, I tried changing it cuz I also used to get an error \headheight is too small (12.0pt) using \setlength\headheight{23.5pt} for example @Christian Hupfer.

Comment: You should be able to take the height `fancyhdr` prints in its warning message on the console and then add `headheight=<tiny bit more than that>` to the arguments you give `geometry`. If you change it manually, `geometry` doesn't know so the text body height stays the same and, unsurprisingly, won't fit in addition to the enlarged `headheight`.

Comment: I have decided to not use the logo anymore and just use \fancyhead[LE,LO]{\changefont \leftmark} which works fine and looks better showing the chapters. thanks a lot for the help ^^